# Splitting dataframe into intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data with times ranging from 0 to 100, and corresponding measurements. I want to subdivide it into intervals of equal time (for example t<1, 1<t<2, etc), which will not necessarily contain an equal number of rows because how the measurements were taken.

Then I can take the average value of measurement over each interval, and compare related data sets.

I can accomplish something of the sort by creating a new dataframe `df1 = df[(df['Time1']>1) & (df['Time1']<2)` for each interval but I'm kind of lost as to how to properly use recursion, or if there is a better method. Programming is not my forte.

A sample of the data set is [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/c1shnxybf0s9yef/sample_data.csv/file).

Comment: Please add a sample of input dataframe in code format (`df.to_dict()`) rather than a link. 1) Links tend to expire 2) People can be cautious of downloading files from external resourses

Comment: It is rather large at 3000 rows, so I can host the requested plaintext here.
https://justpaste.it/7upsk

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

One method is to create an additional column which calculates the appropriate interval and then use groupby() and mean() for aggregate everything. For example

```
import math
import pandas as pd

num_secs = 0.25

df = pd.read_csv(r"sample data.csv")
df['interval'] = (df['Time1'] / num_secs).apply(math.trunc)
df.groupby('interval').agg({'Power1':np.mean})

    
# interval   Power1 
# 0          -12.956747
# 1          -12.909393
# 2          -13.003000
```

Comment: Alternatively using just Pandas: `df['interval'] = df['Time1'].floordiv(num_secs).astype(int)` and `df.groupby('interval')['Power1'].mean()`

Comment: floordiv is a much better way to go, you're right.

Comment: Thanks! This is really neat. How would I best go about performing operations on the groups of rows now? It seems I could now shrink the data set to an equally spaced set of 400 values.

Comment: I don't follow.. The variable num_secs is the number of seconds for each interval. The column 'interval' calculates what each interval in Time1 falls into. Then the groupby function takes the average of all values in that interval. I guess to answer your question, just adjust the variable for num_secs to change how the rows are grouped. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I must have misread your answer and completely missed the last line of code. Thanks again, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [pandas resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) on time index. In order to achieve that we can make **Time1** column into a timestamp in `ms` units. `ms` units are arbitrary in our case, they don't have real meaning behind. It comes with [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) year 1970 artifacts, but as our resampling is relative, that will not matter.

In the code below I resample in "10ms" windows and calculate mean within those windows. Please adjust to the units you actually need.

```
data = pd.read_csv("./sample data.csv")
data["Time1"] = data["Time1"].apply(pd.Timestamp, unit="ms")
data.set_index("Time1").resample("10ms").mean()
```